# How to save and open file order Java GUI

Tags: java

So my problem is is with my last buttonPanel. I don't know how to save and open a file with the GUI, I can get the total but yea help would be appreciated.  "The user should be able to click a button labeled Total that displays the total purchase price in a label (the total should include the Michigan 6% sales tax).  Another button allows the user to Save the order to file.  Yet another button allows the user to Open the order from file."

For saving "Additionally, before a Save is committed, the program should ask the user if they are sure they want to save the file.  They should be able to indicate if they want to save it or not from this pop up dialog.  If the user indicates they do not want to save the file, then the order is not saved.  If they indicate they do want to save it, the file is created (or overwritten) with the new order. The name of the order file is order.txt."

For opening "Your program should be able to open the file as well as saving it.  When the program opens the order, all the GUI components should be set to the appropriate values that reflect the order in the file. If the order.txt file does not yet exist (i.e., an order has never been saved), then a dialog box is displayed telling the user that "no saved order is available", and the main GUI remains unchanged."

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class IcecreamOrdersGUI extends JFrame
{
   private IcecreamFlavorPanel icecreamFlavors;  // iceCreamFlavor panel
   private NutsPanel nuts; //nuts panel
   private SyrupPanel syrup; //syrup panel
   private ScoopsPanel scoops; //scoops panel
   private JPanel buttonPanel; //To hold the buttons
   private JButton saveButton; // To save the order
   private JButton openButton; // to open the order
   private JButton totalButton; //To figure out the total
   private final double TAX_RATE = 0.06; // Sales tax rate

  /**
      Constructor
   */

  public IcecreamOrdersGUI()
  {
         //Display a title.
         setTitle("Icecream Orders");

         //Specify an action for the close button.
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         //Create a BorderLayout manager.
         setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         // Create the custom panels.
         icecreamFlavors = new IcecreamFlavorPanel();
         scoops = new ScoopsPanel();
         nuts = new NutsPanel();
         syrup = new SyrupPanel();

         // Create the button panel.
         buildButtonPanel();

         //Add the components to the content pane.
         add(icecreamFlavors, BorderLayout.WEST);
         add(scoops, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         add(nuts, BorderLayout.NORTH);
         add(syrup, BorderLayout.EAST);
         add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

     //Pack the contents of the window and display it.
     pack();
     setVisible(true);
}

private void buildButtonPanel()
{
   //Create a panel for the buttons.
   buttonPanel = new JPanel();

   //Create the buttons.
   saveButton = new JButton("Save Order");
   openButton = new JButton("Open Order");
   totalButton = new JButton("Total");

   //Register the action listeners.
   saveButton.addActionListener(new saveButtonListener());
   openButton.addActionListener(new openButtonListener());
   totalButton.addActionListener(new totalButtonListener());

   //Add the buttons to the button panel.
   buttonPanel.add(saveButton);
   buttonPanel.add(openButton);
   buttonPanel.add(totalButton);
} 
private class totalButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      //Variables to hold the subtotal, tax, and total
      double subtotal, tax, total;

      //Calculate the subtotal.
      subtotal = icecreamFlavor.getIcecreamFlavorCost() + nuts.getNutsCost() + syrup.getSyrupCost() + scoops.getScoopsCost();

 // Calculate the sales tax
 tax = subtotal * TAX_RATE;

 // Calcuate the total
 total = subtotal + tax;

 //Create a DecimalFormat object to format output.
 DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

 //Display the charges.
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Subtotal: $" + 
              dollar.format(subtotal) + "\n" + 
              "Tax: $" + dollar.format(tax) + "\n" +
              "Total: $" + dollar.format(total));
}
}

/**
Private  inner class that handles the event when
the user clicks the Exit button.
*/

private class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener 
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
     System.exit(0);
}

}

/** 
main method
*/
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     new OrderCalculatorGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: You won't get much help by posting your homework and saying "I don't know how to...". Show what you've tried to do to accomplish that task specifically. Outline what steps you think you need to do, and where you have trouble. Let us know what errors you get and what you've done to try to fix those errors. Also be sure to describe very specifically any details that we need to know, like what a "file order" is. That is something specific to your homework, so we won't even be able to talk about it without more details. Make sure your question is very specific.

Comment: You state that you don't know how to open a file with a GUI, but GUI's don't open files. GUI's provide users with a pretty interface, and can display data from files, but they don't open them. You can use something like a FileReader, or a Scanner, to read from a file. Explain what you mean by using a GUI to open a file please.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good place to look to make sure your questions are answerable and high quality.

Comment: I did post what I tried but I don't know where to go it's not like I just didn't do anything. I wrote the whole thing it's just the last two steps I'm having trouble with like I don't understand "you won't get must help positng your homework and saying I DON'T KNOW HOW TO". I LITERALLY DON'T KNOW HOW TO IF I KNEW I WOULDN'T POST THIS. Anyway the file order is Vanilla
Without_Nuts
With_Cherries
Caramel

Comment: Stephen, I'm not trying to attack you. I want you to get help with your problem, but I need to tell you what *you* need to do to make that happen as soon as possible. I was saying you can't just say "I don't know how to", and not go more in depth with what you don't know how to do. You've included a lot of details, but many of those are just requirements of your program. And those requirements aren't pretty rigid. It would be best if you could take your teacher's words, and turn them into programmer's words. See my next comment for example.

Comment: Your first quote: *"The user should be able to click a button labeled ....."*. It would be very convenient to the question readers if you could turn this into something like, "I need to have a button that will open a certain directory, and when the user chooses a file, it populates a text area..." just for example.

Comment: Ok well for more details I guess I want to implement JFileChooser and the open button would open the order of a previous icecream order and the save button would overwrite the previous file or create a new one if no pre-existing file exists.  uh yea I don't know what else to add, yea my GUI doesn't open file but IN the GUI I need there to be an open and save button that saves the file in the same directory as the GUI

Answer (score -1):

Use JFileChooser to open/save file.  [See usage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)